# How do I capture 'n' inputs in command line for Windows Batch Files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I retrieve multiple user input in windows batch files?

```
@echo off
echo Type tomcat, mvn
set /p input=Enter Selection: 
if /i "%input1%" EQU "tomcat" goto tomcat
if /i "%input%" EQU "mvn" goto maven

 :tomcat
 cd /D C:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.55>start. 
 start .
 GOTO EOF

 :maven
 cd /D C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.2.2
 start .
 GOTO EOF

 :EOF
```

I'm creating a little utility bat file for myself so when I type in tomcat it opens up tomcat or maven if mvn is entered. However, I want to enter something like tomcat deploy which would run the deploy.bat file in the tomcat directory.

Comment: Please, can you explain how this should work? What should the user of the script type? and, what is the expected behaviour? The user will type option1 or option2 or any combination of the options? What to do in any of the cases?

Comment: so if you want to detect `tomcat deploy` or `tomcat undeploy` etc. input and goto different label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse or iterate over the user input using `CALL`, `SHIFT`, `IF` and `GOTO`. Read the `HELP` pages of those commands and then try this code, that should get you started.

First get the user input, and pass it as parameters of a `CALL`

```
set /p input=Enter selection: 
call :doall %input%
goto :eof
```

and then treat the parameters as if they were arguments %1 %2 %3... , `SHIFT`ing them to `%1` and looping with `GOTO` until done (`IF` %1 is empty)

```
:doall
echo %1
shift
if .%1==. goto :eof
goto :doall
```

**or** you can treat each parameter specifically

```
:doall
if /i .%1==.this call :dothis %*
if /i .%1==.that call :dothat %*
goto :eof

:dothis
start this %2 %3 %4
goto :eof
```